# Understanding PCIe lanes for multiple GPU setup

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, motherboard, pci-express

As the title suggests, I am looking to expand my current computer to have multiple GPUs (for mining). Essentially, I want to limit the upfront cost of my investment and therefore I would like to use my current desktop as the mining platform (it will save me from buying another cpu, motherboard, HD, RAM, etc...). Essentially I am having trouble understanding what is possible from the PCIe standpoint.

I currently have an HP Omen (Windows 10) with the Odense2-K motherboard and an i5-7400. There is already a GTX 1060 3GB GPU installed in the PCIe x16 slot and I would like to use the additional PCIe x1 slot with a PCIe expander to add an additional 3 GPUs with a separate power supply for mining cryptocurrencies. From what I have read online, there isn't any clear answer on whether this is possible. Many people have said it worked for them but it will depend on the PCIe lanes available in the motherboard/CPU. I know the CPU has 16 PCIe lanes but I can't find anything on the motherboard.

So my question is twofold:

How can I tell how many lanes are available on the motherboard?

How many lanes will each GPU require? I will be using one GTX 1080 and two GTX 1080ti and want to keep my GTX 1060 just like it is.

Comment: As I stated in the question, I am using an i5-7400 CPU, Odense2-K motherboard (H170 chipset), and a separate PSU for the additional 3 GPUs. But I don't understand what exactly a lane is or how to figure out the number of lanes required per GPU and if the motherboard can support that

Comment: Thank you for letting me know its the chipset that matters and not the motherboard itself, I was able to find that the motherboard has 16 lanes. However, that still doesn't answer the question. I can see the PCIe connectors, they take a 1x slot and give four 16x slots. What I want to know is if that is actually possible to run graphics cards in that format with my hardware since I don't understand how a 1x can go to four 16x and still work if 1x only has 1 lane that will be expanded to 64. Also, would you mind letting me know how could I better format the question?

Comment: But then how do the motherboards made for mining with many more GPUs work? The ASRock Pro BTC+ has 12 1x PCIe ports but an H110 chipset which only supports 6 PCIe lanes. Each one of those 1x PCIe ports are usually connected using a PCIe riser to a 16x port. So by what you are saying, that shouldn't work....

Comment: But from what I saw the H110 has only 6 lanes on the chipset and 16 on the CPU for a total of 22 total. My H170 has 16 lanes on the chipset and 16 on the CPU, so I should be able to run more than the mining motherboards if its all about lanes. I don't see what the number of connectors has to do with it if I can just buy an expander to multiply my number of connectors.

Comment: I dont know much about mining, however I do know that people do not use nvidia cards for it.  AMD GPUs are apparently far better for that task - and also why their prices are inflated.

Comment: I think the other guy that was commenting (@ramhound) was just leading me on because just recently they all went out of stock on Amazon after he deleted all his comments which were not helpful at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How can I tell how many lanes are available on the motherboard?
https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c05355651
Says x16,x1, and the M.2 SSD almost always is give x4 so x21.  They probably use an x1 for something else making it x22.

How many lanes will each GPU require?

Video card can be force into x1 mode.

If you have a board that allow 3 GPU with a x1 connecting plug then you only have x1 worth of bandwidth.  The board has to have a chip on it that buffers or otherwise bring the total available bandwidth down to x1.

Using a pci-e bridge chip or similar:

1. Buffering
2. Each GPU gets 1/3 of x1 all the time
3. Time sharing, each one gets 30ms (or whatever) and then it switches GPU
4. Compression (not 100% effective)
5. Other clever ideas probably exist.

Bottom line:  3 GPU are sharing x1 worth of bandwidth.  In gaming this would kill performance, but I don't know how much bandwidth mining uses.