# How to choose the right GPU topology (PCIe lanes) for multiple GPUs

Tags: graphics-card, desktop-computer, pci-express

I have found some sources on how to choose PCIe lane for multi-GPU setup (like [this one on this site](https://superuser.com/q/1285506/971862)) but still could not find a good reference that answers this question: "How should one choose PCIe lanes when mounting multiple GPUs in particular when PCIe's are coupled with different CPUs?"

I have a HP Z8 G4 workstation (64-based PC) with with these details:

```
OS: Windows 10
CPU: 2 x Intel Xeon Gold 6136 @ 3.00 GHz
BaseBoard Manufacturer: HP
BaseBoard Product: 81C7
BIOS version: HP P60 v02.47 (2/26/2020)
Total physical RAM: 384 GB
```

and 3 Nvidia graphic cards. One will be used for display purposes only and the other 2 will be used for computing purposes:

```
GPU0: Quadro P400 <= Display only
GPU1: Nvidia Tesla k40c <= computing
GPU2: Nvidia Tesla k40c <= computing
```

The PCIe slots look like this:

[image: Image of PCIe slots]

I need to know if it matters how my GPUs are mounted? Are some setups betters than the others? Are there forbidden setups?